# Proving the Grammatical "Correctness" of a Given Phrase/Sentence

Tags: grammar

Unlike some other languages, English has no central authoritative language academy, meaning that there are no definite rules on English grammar.

Keeping this in mind, how would one attempt to prove that the grammar of a specific phrase or sentence is "correct" (i.e. regarded as correct by the majority of the English speaking population)?

Would it be through citing famous pieces of literature in which the same usage occurs? Would it be through citing sources that discuss English grammar or dictionaries (although the information contained within them is limited, meaning they cannot be relied on for every circumstance)?

Comment: Define "correct".

Comment: Of course there are definite rules of English grammar. That is what grammar *is*. It is  the collection of just these rules. If English had no definite rules, English would not exist. To see if a sentence is English or not, you just look at it. There is no famous piece of literature that would list all possible English sentences, and there isn't even a book that would lists all the possible rules.

Comment: Well yes, but I was talking about specific instances of grammar and how they can be proven to be grammatically correct; I wasn't asking if there are definite rules in grammar.

Also, English grammar is not "definite" as regional dialects and variances exist and none is technically the "correct" one. There are some rules regarded by most as correct, which constitutes "English grammar", but they aren't technically objectively correct since no one has the authority to decide that. My question was asking how to show that a grammar rule is widely recognized.

Comment: @tchrist I meant "correct" as in widely recognized. I should have put quotation marks around the word and made that more clear.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Is that enough to get the question reopened? Or, is there something else I need to clarify in the question?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a good objective answer for this, but I do believe it should not be closed for lacking clarity. So, +1 to reopen from me.